# SSH escape sequence in passphrase

Tags: ssh, putty

I need to remove the passphrase from an SSL private key file. I'm using

```
openssl rsa -in in.key.pem -out out.key.pem
```

to do that. The issue I'm facing is that the passphrase for that keyfile (the passphrase is being generated on a different machine somewhere) looks something like this:

```
~Casdfghetc
```

As you've probably figured out, the "~C" part of that passphrase spawns a new command line and leaves me unable to correctly enter the passphrase. Quoting, double-quoting and so forth don't work.
I'm using putty to connect to this shell, hopping through a golden host (powerbroker). This is a productive, secure environment, so I cannot log into the machine any other way. Any tips on how I can get this to work?

Comment: What? Putty handles tilde (~) specially? It's rather strange. I don't understand why "~C" could act as Ctrl+C. 1. Are you sure that you actually press Shift+C (for "C"), not Ctrl+C (and that you press actually Shift+~ (for "~"), not Shift+Escape)? 2. What happens if you try to type some characters between "~" and "C" (and remove them with Backspace)? 3. What happens when you type "~Casdfghetc" in raw bash (e.g. `echo "~Casdfghetc"`)?

Comment: typing ~C in bash instantly spawns a new command line. [This is what's happening](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2010/08/27/ssh-tricks-the-usual-and-beyond/) (search for "SSH Escape Sequences" on that page). To enter the passphrase I actually tried just copy-pasting, entering manually, typing other characters than "C" after the ~, and so on... if I don't get a new command line, the password isn't entered correctly.

EDIT: I should mention that this is an old solaris system, and I have no control over its configuration. As I said, secure production environment.

Comment: @peph Just to be clear, The special treatment of ~C and other tilde sequences isn't an inherent part of the SSH protocol, and it's not documented to be a putty feature. It's a feature of the `ssh` command line utility widely found on unix systems. In your question, you say you're using putty, but you don't say anything about using the `ssh` utility. My guess is that the `ssh` utility with its tilde sequences is involved here, whether you realize it or not. Or maybe it's a putty feature that I missed.

Answer (score 2):

Way 1. As http://www.jedi.be/blog/2010/08/27/ssh-tricks-the-usual-and-beyond/ points out:

> Escape sequences are only recognized after a newline

So, when asked for a passphrase, you can do the following:

1. Type some letter before typing your passphrase, e.g. `a`.
2. Press Backspace key to undo/remove it.
3. Type your passphrase as usual.

Way 2. On my system, pressing "~?" shows the following help:

```
Supported escape sequences:
 ~.   - terminate connection (and any multiplexed sessions)
 ~B   - send a BREAK to the remote system
 ~C   - open a command line
 ~R   - request rekey
 ~V/v - decrease/increase verbosity (LogLevel)
 ~^Z  - suspend ssh
 ~#   - list forwarded connections
 ~&   - background ssh (when waiting for connections to terminate)
 ~?   - this message
 ~~   - send the escape character by typing it twice
(Note that escapes are only recognized immediately after newline.)
```

So, to insert tilde (`~`) right after newline, I need just to press it twice (`~~`). Probably, the same is true for you system: just type `~~Casdfghetc` instead of `~Casdfghetc`.